# Confused about the size of the output of convolution layer in theano deep learning tutorial

Tags: theano, conv-neural-network

[http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html#lenet]

in the above link it says 
 Construct the first convolutional pooling layer:
 filtering reduces the image size to (28-5+1 , 28-5+1) = (24, 24)

convolution of data of size a with filter of size b gives output of size a+b-1. so here the data size 28*28, filter size is 5*5. so the output size should be (28+5-1,28+5-1). it is given as (28-5+1,28-5+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the `border_mode`

[`conv2d`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/signal/conv.html) uses `border_mode='valid'` by default which means (from the [scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html))

> The output consists only of those elements that do not rely on the
>   zero-padding.

So with `border_mode='valid'` and a `(5,5)` filter the output is going to be the same size as the input minus a two pixel border, i.e. `image_shape - filter_shape + 1`, hence with input size `(28,28)` the output is going to be `(24,24)`.

The alternative, `border_mode='full'` will zero pad the input such that the output is of shape `image_shape + filter_shape - 1`.